# Logging not working after replacing the slf4j binding from slf4j-log4j12 -> slf4j-reload4j

Tags: java, apache-spark, log4j, slf4j, java-11

Some background :
My application (Apache Spark) was throwing an exception
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: tlm".

I found a solution to it in https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html. Search for "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError".

As per suggestion, I replaced the slf4j binding I was using which is slf4j-log4j12 with slf4j-reload4j. But now my application can no longer do logging with log4j. No logs are appearing.

here is what I have in application jars dir (related to log4j) :

- slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar
- reload4j-1.2.18.3.jar .
  -logging-interceptor-3.12.12.jar
  -jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.36.jar

Can somebody suggest what's wrong ? I can't back it out the binding since it will bring back the exception. Appreciate any pointers on this . Thanks.